# Returning the number of products in a database

Tags: sqlite

I have made a database with the columns, Product, Quantity, Size and Units. There are 4 products in my db. What would I use if I wanted to return the quantity of a product in the database?

Say I have Bread in my products and have a quantity of 5. How would I get my cmd to output that I have 5 loaves of bread?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: A good start would be learning SQL: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`select quantity, size, units from {table name} where product = 'bread'`

That should get you started.

Note that you're using the word `database` to mean `table`.  A relational database like sqlite contains one or more tables that hold your data in `rows`